# WiFi connection dropping and not detecting networks

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

I am currently facing the next issue in several laptops with Windows 10 and was wondering if anybody could guide me in how to solve it.

Randomly the WiFi connection drops and when you try to manually connect again, no WiFi networks appear available. (I am sure they are up because a laptop just beside this one can see it with no problem)

All laptos are Lenovo.

So far I have tried the following:

- Updating the WiFi adapter drivers to the newest version.
- Updating the bios.
- Modifying the energy setting for the laptop and the WiFi adapter so they never go to sleep mode.

What I also have discover is that if you restart Windows 10 WLAN service, the WiFi networks show up again.

My question is: How could I find out what is causing this issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried an external Usb Wifi Adapter ?

Comment: Yes, and works OK.

Comment: So there is either a problem with the devices or most likely the drivers. Try uninstalling the device on one of the laptops and make sure that you click on `Delete Software Driver` and see if that solves it

Comment: I have also tested that option. Making sure the Delete Software Driver is done but still no luck

Comment: Are there any model-specific drivers available on Lenovo's site? If not, and they're still under warranty, I would send them all back to their maker ...

Answer (score 0):

The comments suggest an issue with the drivers. I wouldn't go as far so quickly. I would first consider that your Wifi adapters might be having issues with the frequencies and or protocols being used on the wireless network. Depending on the standard that the network is broadcasting in (802.11 a/b/g/n) and the channel it is broadcasting in.

- Look up your specific model of wireless adapter and the standards
  it's rated to tx/rx in.
- Should you have other networks in range ( accessible or otherwise ) try to scan the airwaves for what channels they use. (there are apps for this, [Wifi analyser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en_US) comes to mind)
- [Access](https://www.pcmag.com/article/346184/how-to-access-your-wi-fi-routers-settings) your router/Access point and on the wireless settings consider changing the channel that you are broadcasting in to one less used.
- Downgrade/upgrade your wireless standard (802.11 a/b/g/n) to one more in line with the capacities and incompatibilities of your wireless adapter